# How to normalize every bar in stacked histplot to 100 using seaborn or matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization, histogram

I currently have a stacked bar graph which looks like this

[image]

I have plotted this using this piece of code

```
sns.histplot(data=train, x="default", hue="ed", multiple="stack", palette='rainbow', stat='percent')
```

But for the analysis I want to normalise this graph such that both the lengths of the bar graph are same, like using the percentage. For more clarity I would like to do something like this:

[image]

I have also attached my dataset
[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19bkqXKCvUPlIvxCt6ScvPhj25QP08Iso/view?usp=sharing)

```py
data = {'default': [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'ed': [3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: you would normalize the data you plot, but really just dont. Its a terrible choice to represent your data.

Comment: Without normalizing this I'm not sure about how to get some proper inference from the given data.

Comment: what are you trying to infer?

Comment: I'm trying to do EDA on the whole dataset to find the factor effecting default. For this reason I'm trying to plot all these things

Comment: In the histogram, set `discrete=True` since your x-axis is just 0 and 1. The way to get them both as 100, is to plot 0 in a plot and 1 in a separate plot, so separate the data. Also, just because 3.5 shows equal length bars, doesn't mean it's good. That a visual misrepresentation of the data...don't do it